# How to compare two unsorted tables in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to filter-in only the rows from table `Today` which were not in table `Last time` (The first two columns are the identifiers).

These were my failing tries:

```
=IFNA(QUERY(ArrayFormula(if(countif(V8:V30&" "&W8:W30,Q8:Q30&" "&R8:R30)=0,Q8,"")),"select Col1 where Col1 <> ''"), "")
```

Tried to add an `=` in the criterion field.

```
=IFNA(QUERY(ArrayFormula(if(countif(V8:V30&" "&W8:W30,"="&Q8:Q30&" "&R8:R30)=0,Q8,"")),"select Col1 where Col1 <> ''"), "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula

```
=FILTER(A3:D, NOT(COUNTIF(F3:F, A3:A)))
```

[image]

`FRESH` is values in `A` NOT in `F`

#### Reference:

- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks! would this be a good formula to check if the "FRESH" table is empty? `=IF( (SUMPRODUCT(LEN(AB8:AB)>0)) =  0 , "SAME", "NEW")`

Comment: If table is empty, is empty. You can see it. But also `=IF(ROWS(AB8:AB)=COUNTBLANK(AB8:AB),"SAME","NEW")`